# Parsing XML with Python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, parsing, python-2.7, elementtree

I have a long XML document that is structured like this:

```
<carrierData>
    <inspections>
        <inspection inspection_date="2013-01-16" report_state="TX" report_number="TX130G0ELJ05" level="1" time_weight="1">
           <drivers>
              <driver driver_type="Primary Driver" first_name="JOHN" last_name="SMITH" date_of_birth="1962-11-20" license_state="TX" License_number="12345678"/>
              <driver driver_type="CoDriver"/>
           </drivers>
           <vehicles>
               <vehicle unit="1" vehicle_id_number="2HSCAAXN02C039269" unit_type="Truck Tractor" license_state="TX" license_number="1B13577"/>
               <vehicle unit="2" vehicle_id_number="1GRAA76228S702393" unit_type="Semi-Trailer" license_state="TX" license_number="X99757"/>
           </vehicles>
           <violations>
               <violation code="393.11" description="No/defective lighting devices/reflective devices/projected" oos="N" time_severity_weight="3" BASIC="Vehicle Maint."/>
               <violation code="393.53(b)" description="Automatic brake adjuster CMV manufactured on or after 10/20/1994 - air brake" oos="N" time_severity_weight="4" BASIC="Vehicle Maint."/>
               <violation code="393.47(e)" description="Clamp/Roto-Chamber type brake(s) out of adjustment" oos="N" time_severity_weight="4" BASIC="Vehicle Maint."/>
               <violation code="396.3(a)(1)" description="Inspection/repair and maintenance parts and accessories" oos="N" time_severity_weight="2" BASIC="Vehicle Maint."/>
           </violations>
    </inspection>
```

I need to iterate through a list of inspection report numbers and print the first and last name of each driver associated with each number in the list. I am using Python's ElementTree to parse the XML, and though I am not receiving an error with the code below, it is not giving me any results either:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

codes = ['TX3YZ8HQE1X1', 'TX3YAEHQE15W', 'KS00YQ008857', 'TX43D99DAN33', 'NM3267100378',
         'COPF31000853', 'TX3ZYF0MUQ6F', 'TX3ZFC0MHXLU', 'TX3Z760MGU0H', 'TX3YGG0MUQ1R',
         'TX3YBD0MUI0A', 'TX3XPF0MKQYG', 'TX3X8F0MHXA7', 'AZ0160001581', 'TX3WC40ADYGZ',
         'ID6300005350', 'TX3VV50ADUOI', 'TX137S0ELO02', 'UTCE03208119', 'UTCE03208119',
         'TX3UTG0MJKDL', 'TX3UD60MIJU5', 'TX13690EBI05', 'TX3U4E0AFA94', 'TX3U4E0AFA94',
         'TX3T5F0MIJMH', 'TX13550BKL02', 'TX3SLE0MIJGZ', 'TX3SLE0MIJGZ', 'TX3S8D0AFH3D',
         'UTCE03207947', 'TX133Q0ENG01', 'TX133Q0ENG01', 'TX133Q0ENG01', 'TX3REM0MHEK3',
         'ID0000169042', 'COPF05000200', 'TX13280EPV0B', 'TX131S9DAB02', 'CO1E19000017',
         'TX3PD60WAA4L', 'TX1317W1NW07', 'CO2D02000044', 'LALAEQ001266', 'TX130H0EBT06',
         'TX3NW10ABLMK', 'NV7233010192', 'NV4045000998', 'CO3301000406', 'CO5C01000218',
         'TX12949DBU03', 'FL1619000314', 'TX12929DIE02', 'TX128X0AAP01', 'TX128A9DHA07',
         'CO2B01000061', 'TX1274W1DV01', 'TX126Z9DCM01', 'TX127U9DBV01', 'TX127U9DBV01',
         'TX127R9DIZ02', 'TX127K9DCQ06', 'AZ0YDG000141', 'NV7196001031', 'TX126B0FJZ01',
         'TX126I9DAN01', 'LALACV003777', 'CO2B12000014', 'TX12650HTB01', 'ID0000220955']

tree = ET.parse("C:\All_BASICs_07-25-2014.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for x in codes:
    for node in tree.iter('inspection'):
        if ['report_id'] == [x]:
            name = node.attrib.get('first_name','last_name')
            print name
```

I am a programming newbie, so I may be missing something glaringly obvious here, but without an error to reference, I am having trouble tracing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you mean to do with this line?

```
if ['report_id'] == [x]:
```

With this code you're testing `['report_id'] == ['TX3YZ8HQE1X1']`, `['report_id'] == ['TX3YAEHQE15W']`, etc. which will never be true. So that's why your code is exiting without printing anything or giving an error.

There isn't anything named `report_id` in the XML you posted, did you mean `report_number`?

If you want to grab the primary driver's first name for all the `report_number`'s in the `codes` list, try something like this:

```
for x in codes:
    for node in tree.iter('inspection'):
        if node.attrib['report_number'] == x:
            primary_driver = [d for d in node.iter('driver') if d.attrib['driver_type'] == "Primary Driver"]
            primary_driver = primary_driver[0]
            first_name = primary_driver.attrib['first_name']
            last_name = primary_driver.attrib['last_name']
            print first_name, last_name
```

However, there's one performance concern with this code. You're looping over the entire XML document for every code in `codes`. This has [complexity](http://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/) `O(number_of_codes * number_of_records)` which is `O(N**2)`. You can do this in `O(N)` steps instead by looping over the document once and using a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to determine whether a record should be included.

Comment: Thank you, sir! That did it! I did have the correct 'report_number' attribute in my code, but I think I had 'report_id' in there when I first typed it, so sorry for the confusion there. Otherwise, it gave me exactly what I needed and seeing the answers here gave me a much more precise understanding of what I was trying to do. Using the set() function was also suggested above, and I did implement that to great effect. Thanks, again!